# Joomla Site Replication & Automation

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup, backups

Joomla 3.9.20

What's the best way to automate a daily backup of a Joomla website (files, folders & db) to a development site on the same domain?

For example, I have `example.com` and each night I would like to take a snapshot of this and deploy it to `dev.example.com`.

I use Akeeba Backup (Pro) in order to automate site backups, not sure if I can somehow use this along with custom scripting?

The idea is to keep an exact copy of the live site on a development server for testing purposes.

Currently I can use Akeeba in order to backup the site to another domain, but this involves running through the wizard again and setting up the db etc. Wondering if anyone else has been able to achieve something similar? I have some experience with master / slave replication in sql but not attempted this kind of replication before.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Akeeba's Unite https://www.akeeba.com/documentation/unite/introduction.html#what-is-unite UNiTE is an automated, unattended backup archive restoration tool. Since you already have a subscription to Akeeba Backup Pro, it is free to use.

Comment: @TryHarder thanks for this, I never knew it existed!